# JS element innerHTML fails in IE 11 using neptune plugin

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, syntax-error

**Description**: I'm using neptune plugin to open **IE** from other browsers (*chrome*, *firefox* etc).
Assume that when user clicks a button then embedded IE screen is opened.

**The problem:** Javascript fails to execute *getElementById* innerHTML by using neptune

**The error:**   Browser prompts an error that script fails to execute: LINE 1 CHAR 1 (it looks weird, because in this line i haven't any code o.O)

Snippet:

Javascript

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.innerHTML = '<embed id="emb" type="application/x'
+'-meadco-neptune-ax"' + 'pluginspage="http://www.meadroid.com/neptune/download/"\n'
+ 'param-location='
+ "localhost:8080/test/embeddedFromIE"
+ '\n' + 'style="border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; frameborder: 0; overflow: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; scrolling: no"></embed>'
```

HTML

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's probably not a `getElementById` error . . .

Comment: A quick parse reveals you're missing a space between your `type` and `pluginspage` attributes. It might be the problem. There may also be other issues.

Comment: I didn't receive any informative error (it says that line 1 and char 1 fails to execute). All happens when i use neptune plugin...

Comment: Never use that string concatenation syntax. JavaScript implies a `;` at the end of all lines and will try to insert one if it can. Use `+` at the END of your line to make sure the JS parser doesn't insert a statement terminator.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  This code executes correctly for me under IE 11 in edge mode on Windows 7.

Comment: @amphetamachine: While I agree and wouldn't use it, the above *does* actually work (the engine won't insert a `;` before those `+`s). Doesn't mean, though, that there aren't *other* times using that leading `+` rather than a trailing one won't bite the OP.

Comment: @amphetamachine - I wasn't aware the compiler/parser/whatever-its-called even cared about code lines. I thought all excess space like enters and double spaces were ignored/stripped before code execution